# Are there any (pairs of) simple distributions that give rise to a power law ratio?

Tags: probability-distributions

If I recall correctly, for $X$, $Y$ normally distributed, the ratio $X/Y$ is Cauchy-distributed. This is sort of like a power law, but isn't quite. So:

> Are there any simple distributions for two RVs $X$, $Y$ s.t the ratio
>   is really power-law distributed (at least in some regime)?

Comment: I like the question and upvoted it. But is there any motivation for the question?

Comment: I have what appears to be such a data set (corroborated by MLE but I haven't done anything exhaustive). The fits appear excellent. However, it's a small enough data set that I can't easily ID plausible distributions for the ratio (these seem noisier when considered separately).

Comment: @MikeWierzbicki See a more recent discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76175/15941) which indicates that the ratio of an exponential to a gamma is related to, but not quite, Pareto as Wikipedia claims

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76175/15941), Wikipedia's answer to the question posed by the OP is not quite correct.  If $X$ is a Gamma random variable with parameters $(n,1)$ and $Y$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $1$ and $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, then $Y/X$ is *not* a Pareto random variable, 
but $Z = Y/X + 1$ is:
$$P\{Z > z\} = P\{Y/X + 1 > z\} = z^{-n}~ \text{for}~ z > 1.$$
A common scale parameter $\lambda$ could be included in both variables, but since we are looking at ratios, the scale parameter cancels out, and it is convenient to set $\lambda = 1$.

Suppose that $X$ denotes the time of the $n$-th arrival after $t = 0$ in a Poisson process with arrival rate $1$.  Then $X$ is a Gamma random variable with parameters $(n,1)$.  Let $Y$ denote the *additional* waiting time for the $(n+1)$-th arrival.  Then, $Y$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $1$ and is independent of $X$.  Thus, we have the situation described in the previous paragraph.  But notice that the $(n+1)$-th 
arrival time is just $W = Y + X$, and $Z = Y/X + 1 = (Y+X)/X = W/X$ is thus the ratio of the $(n+1)$-th and $n$-th arrival times, and is a Pareto random variable.  Naturally 
$Z > 1$.

> In summary, if $W$ and $X$ are the $(n+1)$-th and $n$-th arrival times in a (homogeneous) Poisson process, then $W/X$ is a Pareto $(1,n)$ random variable:  $P\{W/X > a\} = a^{-n}$ for $a > 1$.

Comment: +1 Nicely done.  I didn't bother with fact-checking as my answer was meant more of a 'point-in-the-right-direction' rather than a 'here's-the-solution.'  More wise advice from Dilip: fact-check your sources.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions), if $X\sim\mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\Gamma (n, \frac{1}{\lambda})$, then $\frac{X}{Y}\sim$[Pareto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)$(1,n)$.

**NOTE:** Wikipedia is not quite right on this one.  See Dilip's response.

Comment: Just a note of caution about notation: $E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ but $E[Y] = \frac{n}{\lambda}$, that is, in Wikipedia's notation, $X \sim \Gamma(1, \frac{1}{\lambda})$ while many other authors would say $X \sim \Gamma(1, \lambda)$

Comment: Wise advice.  **Always** check what notation is being used.